# Clock Time after 30 min interval in listview

Tags: android

i have a listview in my android app in which i am showing list of times of interval of 30 mins. i am hard coding data into the listview using this function

```
    public void prepareTime() {
    ListModel listModel = new ListModel("00:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);

    listModel = new ListModel("01:00 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("01:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("02:00 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("02:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("03:00 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("03:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("04:00 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("04:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("05:00 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("05:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("06:00 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
    listModel = new ListModel("06:30 A.M");
    listModelsList.add(listModel);
ListsAdapter listAdapter = new ListsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listModelsList);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

but i want to add data into the list using mobile time zone using interval of 30 min.
How can i do this?

Comment: how about `TimerTask`

Comment: i want to populate data in listview when the applications starts. Timer Task will take interval of every 30 min to populate data

Comment: load data first time then start the timer ?

Comment: how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After the search i got the answer of my question.

```
 private void displayTimeSlots() {

    String timeValue = "T00:00:4.896+05:30";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    try {
        Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCalendar.setTime(sdf.parse(timeValue));

        if (startCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 30) {
            startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        } else {
            startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // overstep hour and clear minutes
            startCalendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }

        Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCalendar.setTime(startCalendar.getTime());

        // if you want dates for whole next day, uncomment next line
        //endCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        endCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24 - startCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        endCalendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        endCalendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        endCalendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

        SimpleDateFormat slotTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        while (endCalendar.after(startCalendar)) {

            startCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            String slotEndTime = slotTime.format(startCalendar.getTime());

            ListModel listModel = new ListModel(slotEndTime);
            listModelsList.add(listModel);

            ListsAdapter listAdapter = new ListsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listModelsList);
            list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            Log.e("DATE", slotEndTime);
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // date in wrong format
    }
}
```